# Is my User ID supposed to be different than my Document ID for each User in my Users Collection (Firestore)?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I know that this is probably a dumb question, but I'm only starting to learn Firebase/Firestore and I'm having trouble finding the answer that I'm looking for.

I know that I can get the User ID from the currentUser method, but how am I supposed to reference the uid in my file path if the uid and the document id for each user is a different value?

For example, in the reference variable bellow, "HEo4YjfjJ0p2B6hVJRXs" is the document id. If I replace this value with the current user's uid, would it still work the same despite the fact that the uid value is different?

```
var colRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("/users/HEo4YjfjJ0p2B6hVJRXs/Days")
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.  If you want to know if something works, just try it.  Usually people post to Stack Overflow when some code doesn't work the way they expect.  The question then contains the details.

Comment: Don't confuse documentID with userID (uid). Every document in Firestore has a documentID - you can have Firestore dynamically create it or you can manually assign it. Typically, if you have a */users* collection, the documents within that collection would have their documentID manually created and you would use the users uid as the documentID. That makes the data a snap to retrieve as when the user authenticates, you can get their uid and then access their document within the /users collection directly without a query. */users/uid_0*, and */users/uid_1* etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, in the reference variable bellow, "HEo4YjfjJ0p2B6hVJRXs" is the document id.

If that's the id of the document, than that id should be used in your reference, as you already do.

> If I replace this value with the current user's uid, would it still work the same despite the fact that the uid value is different?

If the current user's `uid` is different than the id of the document, then you won't be able to read that document. If you need a document that has as id, the user's `uid` then you should create that document. If you are also thinking about wildcards, please also note that in Firestore there are no wildcards paths to documents. You have to identify collections and documents by their ids.

Comment: @RapsIn4 This is a great answer so please accept it. One clarification *then you won't be able to read that document* is correct in that you wouldn't be able to read the document with `getDocument`, however, it *could* be retrieved by querying the users collection for a field that matches the users uid. That is NOT the best practice for a */users* collection but it would be useful if you wanted to know, for example, which groups a user belongs to - query a */groups* collection for a field that matches the users uid. Hint here is to always reference users by their uid, not a documentID.

Comment: @Jay Thank you, Jay, for commenting and going deeper on this topic.